# Browser refused to frame IdentityServer 3 LogOut Url

Tags: google-chrome, single-sign-on, logout, identityserver3, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement Single Sign Out using idsvr 3, I have two client apps (a MVC 5 and an asp.net core) both registered as clients and logging in works perfect

> MVC 5 - Client A Asp.NET core - Client B

When both apps are logged in and i click on the log out link on Client B , Client A is logged out successfully. But on vice versa (Logging out of Client A first) Client B is not logged out. On checking on the browser's (Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87) console i get the following error

> Refused to frame
>   'https:/client_B/myDomain/Signout_oidc/?sid=2adc40bd3ae432a81671118b09a'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "frame-src 'self' https:/client_B.myDomain https:/client_A.myDomain".

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Damian, I found where the issue was.
Issue was with client A URL, it had an underscore (*) character in it. In some way that violated a CSP rule or something else. Removing the '*' character in the url solved the problem.

Comment: oops Stackoverflow removed the underscore characters from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code to your `IdentityServerOptions` instance.

```
CspOptions = new CspOptions
{
    FrameSrc = "*"
}
```

More information how to configure CSP in IdvSrv3 in the documentation:

- [IdentityServer3 > CSP](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/csp.html)
- [IdentityServer Options](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/identityServerOptions.html)